# this.innerHTML in custom elements

Tags: web-component

I have a web component created with customElements and imported with

`<link rel="import" href="component.html">`

I have this tag `<tag-name>test</tag-name>`

In constructor I have `console.log(this.innerHTML);` but I don't see in console 'text' the console is empty.

```
   (function (thisDoc) {

customElements.define('my-tag', class extends HTMLElement {

            constructor() {
            super();
            var templ = thisDoc.getElementById('templId').content.cloneNode(true);

            this.attachShadow({
                mode: 'open'
            }).appendChild(templ);

            console.log(this.innerHTML);

        }

    });
})(document.currentScript.ownerDocument);
```

Comment: More code please... How are you defining / identifying `this`?

Comment: Same problem. Works perfectly on safari. Not at all on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Browsersync, I tried to serve with express and it works. I don't know why there are problems with Browsersync.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubbleshoot your javascript by right-clicking on an element in your browser and selecting inspect element.

You will find a tab that says *Debug* where you can select the javascript file that has your code and in which you can set breakpoints, for example on the *console.log(this.innerHtml)* line of your code.

Reload your page or activate the script from the front end (UI) and when it stops at your breakpoint you can use the console tab to see if there are any errors in your code, and/or to inspect the values of your different variables.